# How to parse these fields with single regex?

Tags: java, regex

I need to get the **bold** fields with a single regex

<103>CP-MGMT **xpand**[2859]: Configuration changed from localhost by user admin by the service dbset

<31>**routed**[4006]: rt_instance_monitor_job: scheduled next instance monitor in 5 seconds

<134>**CP_FireWall**: 2Jul2017 18:52:23 accept ip address message

I tried with following patterns

```
(?:<\d{1,3}>)\s*(\S+?)(?:\[\d*\])?:(.*) - failed for 1st log

(?:<\d{1,3}>)(?:\S*\s)?([^\[\]]+?)(?:\[\d*\])?:\s(.*) - failed for 2nd and 3rd logs
```

Please excuse any errors on my part. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression,

```
<\d{1,3}>\s*.*?(\S+?)(?:\[\d*\])?\s*:\s*(.*)
```

might simply work OK.

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class re{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        final String regex = "<\\d{1,3}>\\s*.*?(\\S+?)(?:\\[\\d*\\])?\\s*:\\s*(.*)";
        final String string = "<103>CP-MGMT xpand[2859]: Configuration changed from localhost by user admin by the service dbset\n\n"
             + "<31>routed[4006]: rt_instance_monitor_job: scheduled next instance monitor in 5 seconds\n\n"
             + "<134>CP_FireWall: 2Jul2017 18:52:23 accept ip address message";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

#### Output

```
Full match: <103>CP-MGMT xpand[2859]: Configuration changed from localhost by user admin by the service dbset
Group 1: xpand
Group 2: Configuration changed from localhost by user admin by the service dbset
Full match: <31>routed[4006]: rt_instance_monitor_job: scheduled next instance monitor in 5 seconds
Group 1: routed
Group 2: rt_instance_monitor_job: scheduled next instance monitor in 5 seconds
Full match: <134>CP_FireWall: 2Jul2017 18:52:23 accept ip address message
Group 1: CP_FireWall
Group 2: 2Jul2017 18:52:23 accept ip address message
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/RJn7OU/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/RJn7OU/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Emma please check this -> https://regex101.com/r/US5OAP/6/ , in the first log, I need xpand only not CP-MGMT xpand

Comment: @Emma with due respect, that still does not match what OP asked in the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following regex expression:

```
(?:(?<=\s)\w+(?=\[))|(?:(?<=>)\w+(?=\[|:))
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0sKvke/1)

Essentially combining two situations:

1. When word is between a whitespace and a `[`
2. When word is between a `>` and either a `[ or :`

Answer (score 3):

This regex will work for the sample data you have provided:

```
(?:<\d{1,3}>).*?([^[]+?(?=:)|\w+(?=\[\d{4}\]:))
```

It looks for

- 1-3 digits enclosed in `<>`
- a minimal number of characters; followed by either
- a set of non `[` characters followed by a `:` or
- characters followed by some digits enclosed in `[]` and a `:`

The value you want is in Group 1.

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/49wCXY/1)

Comment: Thanks @Nick :)  Sorry I couldn't upvote your answer, Since I dont have that much reputations :( But it helped me a lot.

Comment: @Selva no worries. I'm glad it was of some help.